# average every n rows in a complex matrix

Tags: matlab, average, complex-numbers

I have a big complex single matrix (9040 X 23293).
Because this matrix holds to much data for me, I want to average every n rows. For example, n can be 10 and the new matrix will be 904 X 23293.
I tried to use reshape but it does not work on complex numbers.

I would love to get some help.

Thanks,
Lauren
Thanks.
Laurn

Answer (score 1):

Reshape works on complex numbers. As you did not share the code, I do'nt know what is the problem. Anyhow, if the number of rows is not multiple of 10, you can reshape first `10 * n` rows and add the average of the remain rows. You can find the general solution in the following for the given complex matrix `m`:

```
fixed_num_rows = fix(size(m,1)/n);
means = mean(reshape(m(1:(fixed_num_rows * n),:), fixed_num_rows, n * size(m,2)),2);
means = [means; mean(mean(m((fixed_num_rows * n + 1):size(m,1),:)))];
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I've missed that.